# Remove and restore styles on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a button called `#btn-limone` to remove `filter: "grayscale(100%)"` on first click and on the second click to restore it. I need it to be done through styles and not classes. How can I do this?

```
jQuery("#btn-limone").on("click", function () {
  jQuery("#agrumi_box, #frutta_polpa_bianca_box, #limone_box").removeAttr("style");
});
```

With this I can remove the style but I would like that at the second click it would be brought back to `100%`.

Thank you to anyone who wants to help me

Comment: "_I need it to be done through styles and not classes_" why is that? That code screams for the change of the class on the parent ...

Comment: `$('#btn-limone').on("click", function() { $("#agrumi_box, #frutta_polpa_bianca_box, #limone_box").toggleClass("filtered") })` makes more sense

Comment: Is very complex to explain. Each key is connected with a slice of a svg. Clicking on these buttons will activate a slice and I would like the second click to deactivate the slice with a gray filter. Once the user has played download the modified svg. I saw that the download doesn't work if I apply the classes but only with the styles.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vencie/hbjkrw5g/19/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/km3ycu78/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it has `style` attribute or not, if id doesn't have you can add your style, if it has style you can remove it. like this:

```js
const items = $('.item');

function toggleFilter(button, relevantIndexes) {
  const toggleOn = button.attr('data-toggle') == 'on'
  button.attr('data-toggle', toggleOn ? 'off' : 'on')

  $.each(items, function(index, item) {
    if (!relevantIndexes.includes(index)) return;
    const style = item.getAttribute('style');
    if (toggleOn) {
      item.removeAttribute('style');
    } else {
      item.setAttribute('style', 'filter:grayscale(100%)');
    }
  });
}

$('#btn-limone').on('click', function() {
  const relevantIndexes = [0, 1, 3];
  toggleFilter($(this), relevantIndexes);
});

$('#btn-lime').on('click', function() {
  const relevantIndexes = [1, 2, 3];
  toggleFilter($(this), relevantIndexes);
});
```

```css
.item {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/200x100/a10000/?text=Lemone" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/200x100/a10000/?text=Lemone-Lime" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/200x100/a10000/?text=Lime" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/200x100/a10000/?text=Lemone-Lime" />
  </div>
</div>

<button class="btn" id="btn-limone" data-toggle="off">Limone</button>
<button class="btn" id="btn-lime" data-toggle="off">Lime</button>
```

Comment: At the first click I "turn on" 3 divs, then I click the next button and turn on the corresponding div (because the other two are already on). If I click for the second time on the same button all 3 divs turn off I would like you to check if the button was clicked and turn off only one making the others stay on? I hope I have explained myself.

Comment: https://7c81b.wineqrcode.com/ 
button "lime" "limone"

Comment: I edited my answer, does it meet your requirement?

Comment: I thank you for the modification. I applied your code to mine but I see that it comes out confusing. When a person clicks "lemon" the 3 divs are activated obviously when they click "lime" only "lime" is activated if they were to click on the corresponding button example "lemon" and lime is active it should only deactivate the corresponding wedge and not the other two.